# Using apply (or some other vectorisation) to perform calculation involving two (or more) data frames?

Tags: python, optimization, pandas

I have a dataframe containing information about a ground based instrument at a series of times (i.e. a datetime index). I also have satellite positions for a number of satellites at those same times. These positions are stored in a second data frame. Based on the receiver data I do some processing to work out some predicted observation to each satellite. The resulting data frame then has ntimes x nsatellites data points. Here is my horrible and naive hacked up and completely slow current implmentation. The receiver data is in the DF 'data' and the satellite positions in DF 'sats':

```
data_out = []
time_out = []
for time, state in data.iterrows():
    for stime, row in sats[ sats.index == time].iterrows():
        # Do the calculation given reciever and sat pos and store as dict 'new_row'
        data_out.append(new_row)
        time_out.append(stime)
data_out = pd.DataFrame(data_out,index=time_out)
```

So, I'm not sure how to go about vectorising this. Naively I could split this into two apply statements, each effectively replacing each iterrows call. But is there some other clever approach, as there will still be significant looping overhead with that solution.

Comment: Are you just trying to merge on 'time'?  See docs on ```merge()```, you can do this in one line.

Comment: That's a small part of what needs to be done, there's about 50 lines of calculations I've omitted that are the bulk of the work the needs vectorizing.

Comment: In this case the calculation required for each row is complex, and there's no simple simple way to just use vectorised numpy/pandas commands. The main bottleneck seems to be the series creation in the inner loop.

Comment: Well, post-merge, wouldn't vectorizing be trivial?  After merging the two dataframes, each line contains both instrument and satellite info so you can just use all the standard pandas commands which are already vectorized.  If that doesn't make sense to you, maybe put a couple of sample commands in there to make it more clear what you are doing.  Also never hurts to provide a small example dataset either.